# Изменение урл без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: url, веб-программирование, ajax

Вот тут http://www.usatoday.com/ хорошо видно, что при нажатии на любую новость возвращается лишь часть страницы (firebug), т.е. сама новость, НО урл меняется в адресной строке firefox. Видно, что фон стоит, т.е. это не новая страница.

Еще хорошо такая технология видна в рамблер почте при переходе в разные папки (входящие и тд). на ajax контент меняется, НО урл меняется тоже. не понимаю...

Как это сделали? В общих чертах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/)

Изменение URL в строке адреса будет выглядеть так:

```
$('a').click(function() {  
    $.address.value($(this).attr('href'));  
});
```

На изменение адреса можно назначить обработчик:

```
$.address.change(function(event) {  
    // do something depending on the event.value property, e.g.  
    // $('#content').load(event.value + '.xml');  
});
```

Comment: вау, и не знал, что так можно

Answer (score 1):

```
    var redirect = pageUrl;
    history.pushState('', '', redirect);
```

Это будет работать в новых браузерах, IE начиная с 9 версии.
Есть еще какая-то JS библиотека, которая заставляет работать и в старых браузерах, IE начиная с 6 или 7 версии. Написал наш соотечественник, но я забыл название.